# Check value of count in where clause - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Suppose I have the following table structure:

```
create table sometable (id serial, name varchar(20), Delete_Flag smallint);
```

With the following entries:

```
 id | name | delete_flag
----+------+-------------
  1 | AA   |           1
  2 | BB   |           1
```

Is it possible to write a query to check if the count of total entries in sometable is 2 and that these two entries have name = '**AA**' and '**BB**'? Do not want to write a function but just a simple Query.

Like return **TRUE** if count(*) of sometable =2 and name in ('AA','BB')

else return **FALSE**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you need?

```
select count(*) from sometable having
count(*)  = ( select count(*) from sometable where name in ('AA','BB');
```

Comment: Awesome @Deepika... Worked

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
select (array_agg(name order by name) = array['AA', 'BB']) as flag
from sometable t
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly you looking for exactly 1 AA and 1 BB. So

```
with sometable (name) as
    (values  ('AA'),('BB'))
 select aa_cnt = 1 AND bb_cnt=1
   from (select count(*) FILTER (WHERE name = 'AA') aa_cnt
              , count(*) FILTER (WHERE name = 'BB') bb_cnt
           from sometable
        ) c ;
```

But if name is not unique or 1 is missing

```
with sometable (name) as
    (values ('AA'),('BB'), ('AA') )
 select aa_cnt = 1 AND bb_cnt=1
   from (select count(*) FILTER (WHERE name = 'AA') aa_cnt
              , count(*) FILTER (WHERE name = 'BB') bb_cnt
           from sometable
        ) c;

  with sometable (name) as
    (values ('AA'), ('AA') )
 select aa_cnt = 1 AND bb_cnt=1
   from (select count(*) FILTER (WHERE name = 'AA') aa_cnt
              , count(*) FILTER (WHERE name = 'BB') bb_cnt
           from sometable
        ) c
```

I think the answer by @Deepika would return the correct but invalid result for the last set of data. But I could be totally misreading the requirement.